# Как создать Postgresql сервер на динамическом IP?

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, postgresql

Необходимо создать сервер для базы данных в сети с динамическим IP. Но как после этого к нему подключиться через Интернет с устройства Android?

Comment: Причем тут Android? Все что попало пихали в теги?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у Вас динамический ip- адрес который часто меняется рекомендую использовать сервис [DynDNS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DynDNS) . После чего обращаться к серверу будете не по ip адресу а по доменному имени.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день
Наиболее простым способом будет связаться с Вашим провайдером и оплатить статический ip.
Как альтернатива любой ddns, так бы посоветовал hamachi, но не уверен, что есть аналоги под андроид. Для каких целей будет использоваться postgresql?

Comment: В образовательных, поэтому вариант с оплатой не подходит. Сработал ddns.